# Load custom package model to get model vocabulary in AllenNLP python interface

Tags: allennlp

I'm trying to get the vocabulary from some publicly-available pre-trained models (that aren't mine) using the python interface of AllenNLP, using `self.vocab`. However, I'm running into problems trying to load in the model. I'm looking to get the vocabulary from the [dygiepp](https://github.com/dwadden/dygiepp) models, using the following code:

```
from allennlp.models.model import Model

scierc_model = Model.from_archive('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-research/dygiepp/master/scierc.tar.gz')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConfigurationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/local/63381207/ipykernel_7616/3549263982.py in <module>
----> 1 scierc_model = Model.from_archive('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-research/dygiepp/master/scierc.tar.gz')

~/anaconda3/envs/dygiepp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/models/model.py in from_archive(cls, archive_file, vocab)
    480         from allennlp.models.archival import load_archive  # here to avoid circular imports
    481 
--> 482         model = load_archive(archive_file).model
    483         if vocab:
    484             model.vocab.extend_from_vocab(vocab)

~/anaconda3/envs/dygiepp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/models/archival.py in load_archive(archive_file, cuda_device, overrides, weights_file)
    231         # Instantiate model and dataset readers. Use a duplicate of the config, as it will get consumed.
    232         dataset_reader, validation_dataset_reader = _load_dataset_readers(
--> 233             config.duplicate(), serialization_dir
    234         )
    235         model = _load_model(config.duplicate(), weights_path, serialization_dir, cuda_device)

~/anaconda3/envs/dygiepp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/models/archival.py in _load_dataset_readers(config, serialization_dir)
    267 
    268     dataset_reader = DatasetReader.from_params(
--> 269         dataset_reader_params, serialization_dir=serialization_dir
    270     )
    271     validation_dataset_reader = DatasetReader.from_params(

~/anaconda3/envs/dygiepp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/common/from_params.py in from_params(cls, params, constructor_to_call, constructor_to_inspect, **extras)
    586                 "type",
    587                 choices=as_registrable.list_available(),
--> 588                 default_to_first_choice=default_to_first_choice,
    589             )
    590             subclass, constructor_name = as_registrable.resolve_class_name(choice)

~/anaconda3/envs/dygiepp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/common/params.py in pop_choice(self, key, choices, default_to_first_choice, allow_class_names)
    322                 """{"model": "my_module.models.MyModel"} to have it imported automatically."""
    323             )
--> 324             raise ConfigurationError(message)
    325         return value
    326 

ConfigurationError: dygie not in acceptable choices for dataset_reader.type: ['babi', 'conll2003', 'interleaving', 'multitask', 'multitask_shim', 'sequence_tagging', 'sharded', 'text_classification_json']. You should either use the --include-package flag to make sure the correct module is loaded, or use a fully qualified class name in your config file like {"model": "my_module.models.MyModel"} to have it imported automatically.
```

The error describes how to fix the error from the command line, but not in the python interface. I additionally tried adding the line `import dygie` to my code to import the missing package, but that didn't solve the problem.

Wondering if anyone knows how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

To run this model, you'll need to have the code from this repo: https://github.com/dwadden/dygiepp.

In particular, you need to import the DyGIE dataset reader from here: https://github.com/dwadden/dygiepp/blob/master/dygie/data/dataset_readers/dygie.py#L29

Comment: I already have the repo cloned and have run `conda develop .` from the dygiepp directory, as indicated in the docs to develop `dygie` as a package. The problem I'm having is that even if I include the statement `import dygie`, which runs, the allennlp code still doesn't recognize that dygie exists.

Comment: I also tried `from dygie.models import DyGIE` for good measure, and that didn't work either -- the import worked correctly, but I still got the same error when trying to load the pretained model.

Comment: It's complaining about the dataset reader, not the model. The dataset reader is here: https://github.com/dwadden/dygiepp/blob/master/dygie/data/dataset_readers/dygie.py

Comment: I fixed the original answer so other people don't have to read the comments to figure this out.

Comment: `from dygie.data.dataset_readers.dygie import DyGIEReader` fails with `KeyError: dygie.data`. I checked for typos/path mistakes etc, but can't fix it -- does running that import statement work for you/is there a mistake I missed?

Comment: I'm not trying to run it myself. We can't give that level of support. But that sounds like some problem with the dygie installation?

Comment: Tried again with a fresh install of dygie and it worked! Thanks so much!